# How to route all URLs except some to a PHP file?

Tags: php, apache, routes

I'm working on a PHP project. I want to route all URLs except some (/, /index.php, /video-archive.php etc.) to a PHP file which is /article.php

Let me describe it in more detail:

Consider that I have article.php at URL `https://example.com/article.php`, when a client wants to reach to URL `https://example.com/how-to-grow-beautiful-flowers.php` or without the `.php` extension, I want this request to be processed by this `https://example.com/article.php` URL or simply `article.php` file. If user wants to reach `https://example.com/` or `https://example.com/index.php` or `https://example.com/video-archive.php` they will reach to `index.php` and `video-archive.php`. So there will be exceptions to that route.

```
REQUEST URL                                            PROCESSING URL
https://example.com/                                   https://example.com/index.php
https://example.com/index.php                          https://example.com/index.php
https://example.com/index                              https://example.com/index.php
https://example.com/video-archive                      https://example.com/video-archive.php
https://example.com/video-archive.php                  https://example.com/video-archive.php
https://example.com/how-to-grow-flowers                https://example.com/article.php
https://example.com/types-of-flowers                   https://example.com/article.php
https://example.com/about-us                           https://example.com/article.php
```

NOTE: I'm currently developing this project using XAMPP on my computer (localhost). But I'm planning to deploy it on a server in future. So it should be better to consider this information.

Comment: If this were me, I'd just route everything (except static assets) to a single router file and figure it out in PHP. That way it is server-agnostic, and you don't have to mess around in server configs over and over again. Also, much easier to test.

Comment: @ChrisHaas It sounds like a solid solution. How can do that? Thanks for recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect all requests to `/article.php` expect requests to files that actually exist. Example requests to `/index.php`, `/video-archive.php` and static files will load the actual file. Try this

Put this in a `.htaccess` in the root directory

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect all request to article.php except existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ article.php [QSA,L]
```

You can then get the URI in the `article.php` file like so

```
$article_url = rtrim(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH), '.php');
// when a client hits https://example.com/how-to-grow-beautiful-flowers.php
// $article_url equals '/how-to-grow-beautiful-flowers'
```

Comment: Will try this tomorrow. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Alright. Kindly let me know if it works.

Comment: This works just as I wanted! Thanks for your help!